# Apache htaccess mod rewrite redirection using Controller GET variables in PHP index page

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am working with a custom MVC PHP framework and the index page (acting as a router) receives a GET variable "do" which contains the path that it will route to. If this variable is not set, it defaults to the Auth controller, method login.

```
require_once('config.php');
$controllerAction = isset($_GET['do'])?$_GET['do']:"auth/login";
require_once('core/main.php');
```

Then the index page (source code above) passes this $controllerAction to the main.php file, which autoloads the main controller and then loads the requested controller.

Thus, the URIs in this framework are of the form mysite.com/?do=controller/method/variable and I need it to be in the form mysite.com/controller/method/variable.

Here is the .htaccess file I tried to use, it just didn't work (I have other htaccess files working on the same server so it's not an Apache problem) :(

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?do=$1 [L]
```

Someone suggested that I can do this using PHP but I am not sure how to go about that.

Edit:
The error is that I get "This page cannot be displayed", 404 errors, whenever I try to directly access the mysite.com/controller/method links rather than the default mysite.com?do=controller/method

Further Edit

(please note that other virtual hosts work fine on my localhost):

(XAMPP) Apache Virtual Hosting Info:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:\sites\mysite.com\root\wwwroot"
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com
  <Directory "D:\sites\mysite.com\root\wwwroot">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

File structure (Windows):

```
D:\
--sites
----mysite.com
--------@client_details
--------root
-----------@devfiles
-----------@vars_pwd
-----------wwwroot
--------------config
--------------core
--------------application
------------------controllers
------------------libraries
------------------models
------------------views
----------------------css
----------------------javascript
----------------------images
----------------------icons
```

Comment: are you able to access the index.php without any parameters? just want to make sure that the index.php is reachable.

Comment: Oh thanks it is reachable. It redirects to the index.php?do=auth/login correctly. It just ignores the htaccess file. But if I type in the SEO address directly, I get a 404 :)

Comment: Wow. So no takers on my open bounty? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there are some issues with your `.htaccess` contents. It's always a good idea to not rewrite if a file with the requested name exists. This allows you to have an `img/` folder for your images or any other static content like CSS files, javascript, downloads, etc... The first `RewriteCond` tells Apache to only rewrite if no folder with this name exists. The second one does the same with files. Then you probably want the QSA (i.e. Query String Append) option, which will pass all other `GET` variables to your script.

Under these conditions you can simplify the regex and use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?do=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You might be surprised because this is more or less the same as others posted. I use similar things for many of my projects and I've just tested it, I can guarantee that it works. There must be something wrong with your apache config.

When you have problems with `mod_rewrite`, the first thing you should try is to enable the module itself. Type these commands as root in your shell:

```
a2enmod rewrite
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

The first one activates the module (or complains with `Module rewrite already enabled` if everything is ok) and the second one restarts your Apache server. The path may of course be different on your server.

Then you have to make sure that your VHost config allows you to use `.htaccess` files and do rewrites. This means `AllowOverride` must be set to at least `FileInfo` (or `All`). You could also try to put the rewrite rules right into the config file. Your config should look similar to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ServerName test.example.com
    ServerAlias www.test.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/test/
    <Directory "/home/sites/test/">
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that you have to restart Apache if you change anything in there.

If that all doesn't help, it's always a good idea to have a look at the error logs. On my system, they're located at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (Debian). They might give you more information on what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Sven. This is awesome! I guess the problem was with the QSA option, never heard of it. I would love to accept this but it's not yet fully working. When I access mysite.com it still redirects to mysite.com/?do=auth/login. And when I type in mysite.com/auth/login directly I no longer get 404 errors BUT all images/, css/ and javascript/ files are not loaded from the application/views/ folder.

Comment: My Apache Error log has no errors but my access logs show lines like 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2011:09:46:01 +0100] "GET /auth/application/views/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://mysite.com/auth/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.204 Safari/534.16"

meaning Apache is checking for the application/ folder as if the auth folder exists (it's just a controller). I'm using virtual hosting for my mysite.com on my localhost. Please see edit in my original question for more info. Thanks!

Comment: It's a good thing that you're no longer getting 404 errors, this probably means that the rewrite is okay now. However Apache **won't** change relative paths for you. This means that **you** have to make sure that you send a `Location: auth/login/` header instead of the one with the GET parameter. The same applies for your relative templates/images/css file paths. You'll have to handle that in your code (use absolute paths with the full domain for example), there's no other way. It also doesn't matter that the folder doesn't exist, since the browser can't know that.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?do=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Furicane. I already tried this too, didnt work either. In fact, my main controller used to generate the links as index.php?do=cont/method before I changed it to just ?do=cont/method

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?do=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Codler. When I saw this, i had a gut feeling that it would work because it will handle the "supposed" files and directories, but no it doesn't work yet. Seems we are not far from the answer though...

Comment: Hmm, I dont know if this will be better but, try add "RewriteBase /" after "RewriteEngine On"

Answer (score 2):

Check your apache logs, access logs specifically. If the folder is present in the web root, then you should be able to access it directly :). You might also want to check if you have duplicate virtualhost entries for the same site by chance.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I tried your suggestions too, to no avail :( Of course yes, I can access the page directly. I only want a clean URL, http://www.foobar.com/users/account/5 instead of http://www.foobar.com?do=users/account/5 *sigh* I thought it would be simple but this is just crazy.

Comment: Thanks. My access and error logs are clean. All I'm getting is a 404 on the browser! i.e. the page does not exist. It's trying to open users/account/5 like its present in the file system instead of redirecting via htaccess :(

Answer (score 2):

This one is my customized MVC framework which is based on cake

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?do=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

May be this should help. The typical URL pattern for this site.com/controller/method

Comment: Thanks! I missed out really big on the QSA option

Comment: Not yet, Sai Krishna. Please see my response to Svens and my extra edits in the original question.

Comment: Make this " AllowOverride All" to " AllowOverride None" and see it what it gives.

Comment: Doesn't help matters, Sri Krishna. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your domain setup is like, but here are some suggestions.

If your code resides in the root of your folder, and the index file is called index.php try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?do=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If your website exists in a subfolder e.g. www.example.com/site/, and the index file is index.php Then try the following (change /site/ to whatever your folder is).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/index.php?do=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you still get the 404 error message then do the following:

- Make sure your site allows .htaccess files to be processed by checking AllowOverride is set to all. If you don't have access to the necessary config files to check, a simple test is to setup an .htaccess rule to redirect to a dummy file on your system. If it works, then your .htaccess is being executed fine.
- Have a look at your MVC framework to see what page it's actually sending the request to. The problem may be that you haven't defined a handler for that particular request, and the default action of your MVC framework is to throw a 404 error.

**Edit:** Just reading your description, I notice you said that the URL should basically be something like `mysite.com/?do=controller/method/variable`. If it has be very strict about this format, then you'll also need to put in rules for removing any leading or trailing slashes, e.g. the following re-write rule should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^\?(.*)\?$ /index.php?do=$1 [L,QSA]
```

(This makes the leading and trailing slashes optional, but it should remove them from the actual value you pass to do).